# Python read txt and print

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgthC.jpg]

I can only read one table. I need help with how to read a lot of tables in one txt file.
Thank you very much!

My code looks like this:

```
result=[]

with open('AAA.txt','r') as f:

for line in f:

  result.append(line.split('\t'))

print(result)

for line in result:

    if line[0]=="AAA":

     print(line[0]+" "+line[2]+" "+line[4])
```

Comment: Please see the image. I put the format in it.

Comment: It could be great if you could specify the code for what have you tried and what do you need exactly.

Comment: the format of the text will remain same or change ? (that you specified in an image)

Comment: Thank you for yours comment ^^. The format for each table is same, change number only. I don't know how to read lot of tables in the one txt file.

Comment: Can you please tell me number of spaces in between 2 words or numbers ?

Comment: In the tables I use tab(\t) between 2 words or numbers. like this: AAA(tab)BOOK(tab)1(tab)FOOD(tab)1

Comment: @owen I have updated the below answer and now is working for tabs, just split based on what you have in btw numbers or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample code that will print table according to your specified image.

**CODE**

```
with open('table.txt', 'r') as table:
    while True:
        try:
            row1 = [i.strip() for i in table.readline().split('\t')] # Split based on number of spaces in btw 2 values or numbers
            row2 = [i.strip() for i in table.readline().split('\t')]
            print row1[0] + ' ' + row1[2] + ' ' + row1[4] + ' ' + row2[2] + ' ' + row2[4]
        except:
            break
```

**FILE** (table.txt)

```
AAA BOOK    1   FOOD    1
    BOOK    3   FOOD    4
AAA BOOK    1   FOOD    1
    BOOK    3   FOOD    4
AAA BOOK    1   FOOD    1
    BOOK    3   FOOD    4
AAA BOOK    1   FOOD    1
    BOOK    3   FOOD    4
AAA BOOK    1   FOOD    1
    BOOK    3   FOOD    4
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Please do let me know if you face any problem running the above code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^^! I put my code in the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!

I can run it. My code like this:

```
with open('AAA.txt', 'r') as table:
  while True:
    try:
        row1 = [i.strip() for i in table.readline().split('\t')] 
        row2 = [i.strip() for i in table.readline().split('\t')]
        row3 = [i.strip() for i in table.readline().split('\t')]
        print row1[0] + ' ' + row1[2] + ' ' + row1[4] + ' ' + row2[2] + ' ' + row2[4]
    except:
        break
```

I added row3 because there is an "enter" in the txt.

Thank your very much! ^^!